# Yom Kippur - Soul or Body

Tags: words, yom-kippur, soul, parshat-acharei-mot

The *Torah* (*Vayikra* 16:31) says "וְעִנִּיתֶ֖ם אֶת־נַפְשֹֽׁתֵיכֶ֑ם, *You shall afflict yourselves."*  - this is a reference to *Yom Kippur*. Artscroll translates נַפְשֹֽׁתֵיכֶ֑ם to mean *yourselves*, but literately, the word נַפְשֹֽׁתֵיכֶ֑ם means *your souls*.
On *Yom Kippur* we are abstaining from physical pleasures. Our bodies are physical and are souls are spiritual.

Why doesn't the *Torah* say וְעִנִּיתֶ֖ם אֶת־גופיכֶ֑ם, You shall afflict your bodies? For if anything, we depriving our **bodies** from *food* and *drink* not our **souls**?

Comment: What if נפשותיכם meant literally _your throats_? That would make a lot of sense, actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word נפש is not limited to mean strictly "souls."  It often means something along the lines of "life force" or "being."  When someone kills someone else, the Torah refers to it as having struck the נפש - as in אדרוש את נפש האדם of [Bereishit 9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8173), or מכה נפש of [Bamidbar 35](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9963), or רצחו נפש of [Devarim 22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9986).  נפש תחת נפש ([Vayikra 24](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9925)) seems to mean "a life for a life."

ועניתם את נפשותכם then would mean to afflict your life, or your life-force, which means to weaken it through abstaining from that which provides it with sustenance.

The Malbim (in הכרמל, under "נפש") shows that נפש often refers to the body, and sometimes even to a dead body.  See it [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32825&st=&pgnum=492).

נפש is not an alternative choice to גוף - it is the Biblical word used for it.  גוף [only appears in one verse in Tanach](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t25a10.htm), in the context of meaning a corpse.

Comment: So people can find it in case the link dies. Nice answer!

Comment: Then what is the difference between גוף and נפש?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I assume you are asking on the Malbim's explanation.  In my first point, the difference is obvious.  But the truth is, the word גוף does not appear in Tanach.  The Biblical word for it is "נפש"

Comment: What is difference between נפש and נשמה?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Why don't you [ask](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)?